# Getting 405 on PUT request nginx server

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, put, http-status-code-405

Getting 405 error on Put request.

Example URL : http://somedomain.com/test/

Strangely  when I access that url using absolute path (http://somedomain.com/test/index.php OR http://somedomain.com/test.php) it gives proper response.

As suggested by some google links, I have tried adding nginx directive in my conf file

`dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;`

But then it starts giving me HTTP 409 error.

In actual I have a wordpress endpoint BASE_URL/wc-api/v3/products/{product_id} (API endpoint to update product) and need to allow PUT request on this URL, but kind of stuck and can't find any solution for same.

What needs to be done here? If anyone came across same issue please help.

Thanks in advance.